# limit characters displayed in div without losing formatting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have found a code to limit characters in div but it's not working when my string is formatted in html.

```
var myDiv = $('.credits');
myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,162));
```

I want to limit the characters in div but without losing formatting. I can use php, javascript or jquery.

Thanks for your help in advance.

HTML structure of myDiv:

```
<p>this is my test <b>hello</b> <i>world</i></p>
```

Comment: Provide the HTML structure of 'myDiv'

Comment: Suppose your "formatting" means a DOM tree, then you have to parse the entire tree to maintain the format. Now take a look at this page, or any page, how do you, or anyone, trim the text without losing its format? If no one can do it, then no one can answer this question.

Comment: This is the html structure of myDiv : <p>this is my test <b>hello</b> <i>world</i></p>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<body>
<div id="test_div">
<h1>TITRE</h1>
<p><strong>Texte en gras</strong><br />
<em>Texte en italique</em><i> texte avec balise i</i> <span>texte normale </span><strong> autre gras</strong></p>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    var nb_limit=5 ,nb_all_charac=0,clean_all=false;
    var fonc_clean_balise=function($v_element,maxi_chara){
        if($v_element.children().length)
            $v_element.children().each(function(index, element) {
                var $child=$(element);
                fonc_clean_balise($child,maxi_chara);
                maxi_chara=(maxi_chara-$child.text().length);
                maxi_chara=(maxi_chara<0)?0:maxi_chara;

            });
        else{
            $v_element.text($v_element.text().substring(0,maxi_chara));
        }
    };
    $('#test_div').children().each(function(index, element) {
        $element=$(element);
        if(!clean_all){
            nb_all_charac+=$element.text().length;
            if(nb_all_charac>nb_limit){
                clean_all=true;
                var lower_limit=nb_limit-nb_all_charac;
                nb_limit=(lower_limit<0)?nb_limit:lower_limit;
                fonc_clean_balise($element,nb_limit);
            }
        }else{
            fonc_clean_balise($element,0);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. it works great but my html is like this:
<p>this is my test <b>hello</b> <i>world</i></p>

Comment: if a text has no formatting, places it in a span
For example:
<p><span>this is my test</span> <b>hello</b> <i>world</i></p>